# How do you add a user using --gecos Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, useradd

I am trying to create a script that adds a user, but I have to do it in a non-interactive way without the default prompts of the adduser command. The instructions I have state that I should use --grecos, but I have looked everywhere to get more information on this and I cannot find anything helpful.

The best that I found was this:

[image]

But I don't know what the empty string represents (" ") and I do not know what the argument "username" represents. Is it that the username will be named an empty string?

Would someone be able to explain?

This is what is supposed to be done in the script:

[image]

Would anyone be able to help me with this?

Thank you all very much!

Comment: Welcome to SE. This seems like homework to me and you are better off trying to solve it yourself. There is a manpage on `useradd` For example you can access it using `man useradd`  and look for the `-c` flag.

Comment: Thank you! And it is homework, but my professor is not very good at explaining things and personally I only find manpages to be helpful in certain circumstances. I looked up info for -grecos in the manpages and it confused me even more. So I was just looking for assistance with understanding it, not for it to be completed lol

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting for commands and quote formatting for regular text. https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

> `adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" username`

> I don't know what the empty string represents (" ")

The empty string means exactly that you don't intend to populate the GECOS field with anything meaningful. The `--gecos` option expects an argument (as seen in the GECOS part of `--gecos GECOS` in the man page), so you have to give it *something*, and the empty string is *something*. It looks like the assignment expects you to use the name and email fields to populate the GECOS field, though!

> I do not know what the argument "username" represents. Is it that the username will be named an empty string?

Understanding a command's options and arguments is essential to achieving the results you want with that command. As noted, the `--gecos` option is looking for the text you want to set in the GECOS field; the empty string is what you're giving it. The `adduser` command itself expects a separate argument so that it knows what to call the new user -- that's the `username` that you supply (probably in `$username` from your script).